# Sorting an observable array, which has queried data returned by breezeJS

Tags: sorting, knockout.js, breeze

[image: Image of an observableArray coming while queryinq database using breeze]

The above image is of observableArray which is coming while queryinq database using breezeJS (using EntityManager).

My question is that

> how do we sort this observable based on some criteria i.e.,
>   (object.attributeName) ?

So that this array is sorted based on some attribute name and we can simply use the observable within foreach bindings and use them in sorted way because I don't wanna query all the time (locally or from server) to get data in sorted order.

Comment: try `latestvalue().sort(function (a, b) { return a.someAttr() > b.someAttr() ? 1 : -1 })` which should work . cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So make a computed

```
var orderDirection = ko.observable(1);
var orderField = ko.observable("id");
var orderedObsArr = ko.computed(function(){
     var oDir = orderDirection();
     var oField = orderField();
     var newArr = originalObsArr().slice(0);
     newArr.sort(function(a,b){
         return oDir * (a[oField] > b[oField] ? 1 : -1);
     });
     return newArr;
});
```

so to change to a sort by `name` descending, you simply change:

```
orderDirection(-1);
orderField("name");
```

and your computed dependent `orderedObsArr` will be updated.

See [this pen](http://codepen.io/spender/pen/LVzpxZ?editors=101) for a working example.

Comment: Nice. Just want to stress the **importance of obsArr().slice**: this makes sure the array sorted is a *copy* of the original array, so that the original array stays unmodified in order.