# OrderBy dependentObservable in an observableArray

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, breeze, durandal, hottowel

I have a function which returns an observableArray

`function refreshRoom(room) {
                return entityQuery.fromEntities(room)
                    .expand('messages, userRooms.user')
                    .using(manager).execute()
                    .then(querySucceeded)
                    .fail(queryFailed);
            }`

Here is the content of the array

[image]

I want to be able to orderBy "Created" property, which is dependentObservable from the "Messages" observable. As u can see from the above code, I expand "Messages" from my Room entity.

I tried to achieve this with `orderBy('messages.created')` but obviously that doesn't work.

So how can I order my messages according the "Created" property?

Comment: messages.created() ?

Comment: It doesn't work either. Actually I think breeze doesn't support orderBy after expand

Comment: using `messages.sort(function(l,r) return l.created().getTime() == r.created().getTime() ? 0 : (l.created().getTime() < r.created().getTime() ? -1 : 1) )` could help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30913848/sorting-an-observable-array-which-has-queried-data-returned-by-breezejs